# Tracking for URL domain forwarding

Tags: tracking, domain-forwarding

I have a landing page (provided to me and I have no access o control over it).  I want to track how many clicks I get, so I want a new domain name (from GoDaddy) to forward to my landing page, but I a way to track how many times this domain gets used.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's not difficult really. When they hit your domain do whatever tracking you want (i.e. logging to a database) then forward them with a 303 redirect to the landing page.

Another option (don't know if this is actually possible), forward the domain to a URL shortener which offers tracking.

Comment: The domain name I have at GD is just a name, there is no server or page there to add any tracking to - it just forwards though GD to the final destination.  I was hopeing not to have to host a page somewhere else, add tracking code, then re-direct again to the final destination.

Comment: I added another option but don't know if it works. If all you're doing is forwarding you don't have many options.